# WSAGetLastError() returns 64?

Tags: socketexception

When i use WSAGetLastError() in my application, it returns 64. Can anyone please explain what 64 means? the client is getting disconnected when we get this error?

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate the language used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket error codes start at 10000.  64 is not a [documented socket error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668.aspx) that `WSAGetLastError()` can return.  However, Windows error code 64 is `ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED` ("The specified network name is no longer available.").